# Unable to uninstall previous anaconda version after installing the latest version without installing previous version

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I installed the latest version of Anaconda over the previous version because it malfunctioned (the anaconda navigator was not opening). However, even on repeated attempts, I am unable to uninstall of the previous version even on uninstalling it from the control panel. Please let me know what should i do to uninstall the previous anaconda version completely.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the docs: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/
2. Install the Anaconda-Clean package from Anaconda Prompt

```
conda install anaconda-clean
```

3. Remove all Anaconda-related files and directories

```
anaconda-clean --yes
```